# Find values in a text string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, parsing

I'm reading XML files, but these **are not correctly formed**, so I'm reading them by text functions. My problem is that I need get values from tags that are diferent, for example:

[image: xml]

What I need is the values from last tag, for example: 15.000, 9.490 and 9.220.

I read the files:

```
public string Leer(string archivo)
{
    string texto;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(archivo, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        texto = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return texto;
}
```

I read the segment of the strig, that contains numeric values:

```
public string getRango(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End-3500);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I try to get values using regex, for isolating only numeric values from text.

```
public string extraerValor(string str)
{
    string patron = @"\d+(\.\d{1,3})?";
    string input = "";

    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(str, patron))
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(str, "[a-zA-Z]*", string.Empty);
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Nada";
    }
}
```

So, I use a DataTable for getting all values that I read:

```
 CartDT.Columns.Add("rango", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("ValorExtraido", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("nombreArchivo", typeof(string));
```

And I read values and send to gridview:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.xml"))
    {
        try
        {
            string lecturaXML = b.Leer(file);
            string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

            dr = CartDT.NewRow();
            dr["rango"] = b.getRango(lecturaXML, "<campoAdicional nombre=" + @"""TASA DE RECOLECCION DE BASURA", "</campoAdicional>");
            dr["ValorExtraido"] = b.extraerValor(b.getRango(lecturaXML, "<campoAdicional nombre=" + @"""TASA DE RECOLECCION DE BASURA", "</campoAdicional>").ToString());
            dr["nombreArchivo"] = nombreArchivo;


            CartDT.Rows.Add(dr);


        }
        catch (System.Xml.XmlException)//Excepcion en caso de xml mal formado
        { }

    }

    //mandar la informacion a la grilla
    gvwFacturas.DataSource = CartDT;
    gvwFacturas.DataBind();

}
```

It means, I want to read:
campoAdicional nombre="TASA DE RECOLECCION DE BASURA (WHATEVER)........... 5.490 .............(more data) ...."
But I only want the numeric value (5.490)

And This the result:
[image: grid]

And I can't get numeric values.

Is there any way to get them?
please, I hope anyone can help me.

Best Regards

Comment: Why is the data not properly formed? You could try to parse it and expect unformed data but that just asks for hacks on top of hacks.

Comment: what do you mean "they are not correctly formed", clearly the first point of interest should be to correct the xml and then you may look at XDocument or XmlDocument classes

Answer (score 2):

When the tag format is unknown, you can use regex pattern matching.  I've tossed together a basic example but it should get you on the right path.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParsingDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var matches = Regex.Matches(GetData(), "\".+?\"\\>\\d+\\.\\d+");

            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                var key = Regex.Match(m.Value, "\".+?\"");
                var value = Regex.Match(m.Value, "\\d+\\.\\d+");

                Console.WriteLine("Key is " + key.Value.Trim('"'));
                Console.WriteLine("Value is " + value.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string GetData()
        {
            return
                "<campoAdicional nombre=\"asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    1s     \">239.220</campoAdicional>" +
                "<campoAdicional nombre=\"asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    213     \">1229.220</campoAdicional>" +
                "<campoAdicional nombre=\"asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh   fds       \">  9.220</campoAdicional>";
        }
    }
}
```

And the result would be the following:

```
Key is asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    1s
Value is 239.220
Key is asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    213
Value is 1229.220
```

If white-space is allowed to proceed the decimal values, you can make a slight change to the pattern.  eg. Change the pattern to: "\".+?\"\>(\s+)?\d+\.\d+"

The result would then be:

```
Key is asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    1s
Value is 239.220
Key is asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh    213
Value is 1229.220
Key is asdfasdhkjh fdsafhsdfkjh   fds
Value is 9.220
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the XML is not correctly formed, you just need to use a form of wildcard search to find the part that you want.

Using XDocument is going to be much more reliable than parsing this data line by line:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
var vals = from n in doc.Descendants("campAdicional") where n.Attribute("nombre").Value.ToString().StartsWith("TASA DE RECOLECCION DE BASURA") select n;
foreach (XElement x in vals)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(x.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your regular expression. If you replace your pattern with the below pattern, you can get your number from MyNumber group.
<.*>(?\d.\d{3})<.*>